# Are items shared when hiding alone?

Tags: city-of-horror

If you hide alone in City of Horror, do items still get shared (to yourself) even though no vote takes place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**. When hiding, you are not allowed to vote. Since there are no votes, the outcome is considered a tie, and in the case of a tie, no one gets anything. The items remain on the location.

In the FAQ ([PDF](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/CITY_OF_HORROR_FAQ_USA.pdf)):

> Q: Can a hidden character (Little Girl or Little Boy’s power, or Hiding action card) take part in sharing anything?
>   A: The character can’t vote, but can receive an item.

And on page 6 of the Rules ([PDF](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/CITY_OF_HORROR_RULES_USA.pdf)):

> Be careful: in case of a tie in the sharing vote, no players get anything. They remain on the location.

Comment: Thank you for this! That's what I figured, and in fact the exact argument I put up. +1

Comment: @JimHurley No problem. Welcome to the site!